# The APM Agent is not functioning on the VM (ELK Stack)

Tags: go, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack, apm

I have an issue regarding APM and ELK that I installed in Docker. The following docker-compose.yaml runs on my local computer, and APM functions properly to instrument Golang. However, when I run this docker-compose on VM 172.16.4.42, the APM agent does not work. Is there any configuration mistake?

following contents of the file docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:7.13.0
    cap_add: ["CHOWN", "DAC_OVERRIDE", "SETGID", "SETUID"]
    cap_drop: ["ALL"]
    ports:
    - 8200:8200
    command: >
       apm-server -e
         -E apm-server.rum.enabled=true
         -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601
         -E setup.template.settings.index.number_of_replicas=0
         -E apm-server.kibana.enabled=true
         -E apm-server.kibana.host=kibana:5601
         -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 12
      test: curl --write-out 'HTTP %{http_code}' --fail --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8200/
    networks:
      - elastic

  elasticsearch:
   container_name: elasticsearch
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.0
   ports:
    - 9200:9200
   environment:
    - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
    - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    - discovery.type=single-node
   networks:
    - elastic

  kibana:
   container_name: kibana
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.13.0
   ports:
    - 5601:5601
   depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
   environment:
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200
    - xpack.apm.enabled=false
   networks:
    - elastic
  
  goservice:
    build: "."
    ports:
      - "8102:3003"
    environment:
      - "ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME=apm-nemo"
      - "ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL=http://apm-server:8200"
    networks:
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      apm-server:
        condition: service_healthy  

  
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```